# reporting services in vb.net - report viewer

Tags: .net

I havea report viewer on my frmReports. I've created 2 reports, Report1.rdlc and Report2.rdlc. I have a strongly defined DataSet - with two DataTables (1, 2) for each report respectively. I'm trying to be able to use that same reportViewer in displaying both reports.

Currently I have two buttons (1 for each report) so that on button click - I query against SQL SERVER to get data and load it into each DataTable like this..

```
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Con)
    adapter.Fill(ds)

    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "DataTable1"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WindowsApplication1.Report1.rdlc"
    DataTable1BindingSource.DataSource = ds
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

I do the same thing for Report2 but with DataTable2 and I change EmbededResource to Report2 and DataTable Binding to DataTable2.

The thing is, one of the report has to be pre-selected in CHOOSE REPORT before I run my application - so if Report1.rdlc is preselected - then when I debug it and run Report1 it runs perfectly fine. However, when it's not letting me run Report2 in that case.

I've tried using these two functions on Form_Load (in that case the report viewer is empty and should only be populated if user clicks on any one of the buttons.

```
ReportViewer1.Reset()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
```

but it tells me that

> Data source instance has not been supplied for data source DataSet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems to be an issue that not many people know the solution to.....well here it is. At least how I've done it for anyone else that might come across the same issue.

I created a strongly defined DataSet1 - within it i have DataTable1 with exact fields I'm selecitng in my Query. I also have DataTable2 for Report2. So this code is the same for the most part - for both Reports, I only change the references to Report2 and DataTable2.

```
 Me.ReportViewer1.Reset()

 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WindowsApplication1.Report1.rdlc"
 sql = "SELECT RecBy, RecOn from tblNotes"

 adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
 adapter.Fill(ds, "DataTable1")

 Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("DataTable1"))
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
 ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Need these at the top....

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
```